# What is the name of the island used in Ocean Girl?

Tags: real-location, ocean-girl

What is the name of the island used in *Ocean Girl*? Is it a real island in Australia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Neri's island was never named in the series, so I doubt the in-universe location can be identified with a real location.

Out of universe, scenes set there were filmed on [High Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Island_%28Queensland%29), part of the Frankland Islands in North Queensland. From [OceanGirl.org](http://www.oceangirl.org/archive/html/0m.html), which is an excellent resource for all information about the show:

> Most of the outside/island shots were taken on locations ’round Port Douglas and as “Neri’s Island”, High Island, which is part of the Frankland national park Islands of Cairns, Queensland, Australia.